# VB.NET equivalent of CommandBars

Tags: vb.net, vba, winforms, excel

I have this code in VBA (shown in a simplified version) :

```
Sub TheMenu()
    Dim Obj As CommandBar
    Set Obj = Application.CommandBars.Add(Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
    Obj.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton).Caption = "Button1"
    Obj.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton).Caption = "Button2"
    Obj.ShowPopup
End Sub
```

I wish to make something equivalent (meaning "that looks similar and has similar uses", I don't need more) in VB.NET. Do you know any way of doing so?
[image: Excel VBA rendering]

I am using in VS2015, a "Windows Forms application" project using .NET framework 4.6.1 .

Comment: I have auccessfully used almost exactly the same with VSTO, apart syntactical changes. i.e. no `Set`, `Type:=MsoControlType.msoControlButton` etc... (Well a atually I used `Controls.Add(1)` I dont remember if there was a specific reason).

Comment: All those types are unknown in my visual studio... What Imports did you use?

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Core`, `Microsoft.Office.Interop`, `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. But the project was created through VSTO so IDR if these were added automatically. Had done this years ago but since moved "back" to VBA :). Also I see in the project `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common`,  `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel` and a few other things, I guess VSTO added them since the project was created as Workbook project.

Comment: Downvoted. What's not clear at all, is what you're intending to do. VBA code runs embedded in Excel. Are you asking about doing the equivalent in VB.NET (in a VSTO/Excel solution), or about "having something that looks like a context menu in a {insert UI framework here} application written in VB.NET"? - The answer is **WILDLY** different depending on whether you're making a VSTO/Excel solution, a WinForms app, or a WPF app.

Comment: @A.S.H none of these imports seems to achieve anything... Does my code compile on your side (apart from the "set" obviously)

Comment: @Mat'sMug : I am editing my question accordingly. I merely need something that serves the same use, thus that looks similar, which I can click upon, in a regular VB.NET program

Comment: I think the answer was given by @Mat'sMug; my own project is a `VSTO/Excel Workbook` so much of the references and imports were added autmatically.

Comment: @Mat'sMug : indeed.You are a fast one! I found out and edited it again while you were answering :-) Does it answer now? (PS: on second thought, commenting BEFORE editing was kind of stupid of me)

Comment: I am investigating contextmenustrip , it might indeed answer my need. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the example bellow here:

```
Public Class Connect
   Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2
   Implements IDTCommandTarget

   Private Const MY_COMMAND_NAME As String = "MyCommand"

   Private applicationObject As EnvDTE.DTE
   Private addInInstance As EnvDTE.AddIn
   Private myStandardCommandBarControl As CommandBarControl
   Private myToolsCommandBarControl As CommandBarControl
   Private myCodeWindowCommandBarControl As CommandBarControl
   Private myTemporaryToolbar As CommandBar
   Private myTemporaryCommandBarPopup As CommandBarPopup

   Public Sub OnConnection(ByVal application As Object, ByVal connectMode _
      As Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode, ByVal addInInst As Object, _
      ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnConnection

      Dim myCommand As Command
      Dim standardCommandBar As CommandBar
      Dim menuCommandBar As CommandBar
      Dim toolsCommandBar As CommandBar
      Dim codeCommandBar As CommandBar
      Dim toolsCommandBarControl As CommandBarControl
      Dim myCommandBarButton As CommandBarButton
      Dim position As Integer

      Try

         applicationObject = CType(application, EnvDTE.DTE)
         addInInstance = CType(addInInst, EnvDTE.AddIn)

         Select Case connectMode

            Case ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_AfterStartup, ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Startup

               ' Try to retrieve the command, just in case it was already created
               Try
                  myCommand = applicationObject.Commands.Item(addInInstance.ProgID & "." & "MyCommand")
               Catch
               End Try

               ' Add the command if it does not exists
               If myCommand Is Nothing Then

                  myCommand = applicationObject.Commands.AddNamedCommand(addInInstance, _
                     "MyCommand", "MyCommand", "Executes the command for MyAddin", True, 59, Nothing, _
                     vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported Or vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled)

               End If

               ' Retrieve some built-in command bars
               standardCommandBar = applicationObject.CommandBars.Item("Standard")
               menuCommandBar = applicationObject.CommandBars.Item("MenuBar")
               toolsCommandBar = applicationObject.CommandBars.Item("Tools")
               codeCommandBar = applicationObject.CommandBars.Item("Code Window")

               ' Add a button to the built-in "Standard" toolbar
               myStandardCommandBarControl = myCommand.AddControl(standardCommandBar, _
                  standardCommandBar.Controls.Count + 1)

               myStandardCommandBarControl.Caption = MY_COMMAND_NAME

               ' Change the button style, which must be done casting the control to a button
               myCommandBarButton = DirectCast(myStandardCommandBarControl, CommandBarButton)
               myCommandBarButton.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIcon

               ' Add a button to the built-in "Tools" menu
               myToolsCommandBarControl = myCommand.AddControl(toolsCommandBar, toolsCommandBar.Controls.Count + 1)
               myToolsCommandBarControl.Caption = MY_COMMAND_NAME

               ' Add a button to the built-in "Code Window" context menu
               myCodeWindowCommandBarControl = myCommand.AddControl(codeCommandBar, codeCommandBar.Controls.Count + 1)
               myCodeWindowCommandBarControl.Caption = MY_COMMAND_NAME

               ' Add a new toolbar with a button on it
               myTemporaryToolbar = applicationObject.CommandBars.Add("MyTemporaryToolbar", _
                  MsoBarPosition.msoBarTop, System.Type.Missing, True)

               ' Change the button style, which must be done casting the control to a button
               myCommandBarButton = DirectCast(myCommand.AddControl(myTemporaryToolbar), CommandBarButton)
               myCommandBarButton.Style = MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonIcon

               ' Make visible the toolbar
               myTemporaryToolbar.Visible = True

               ' Calculate the position of a new command bar popup by the "Tools" menu
               toolsCommandBarControl = DirectCast(toolsCommandBar.Parent, CommandBarControl)
               position = toolsCommandBarControl.Index + 1

               ' Add a new command bar popup with a button on it
               myTemporaryCommandBarPopup = DirectCast(menuCommandBar.Controls.Add( _
                  MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, System.Type.Missing, System.Type.Missing, _
                  position, True), CommandBarPopup)

               myTemporaryCommandBarPopup.CommandBar.Name = "MyTemporaryCommandBarPopup"
               myTemporaryCommandBarPopup.Caption = "My menu"
               myCommand.AddControl(myTemporaryCommandBarPopup.CommandBar)
               myTemporaryCommandBarPopup.Visible = True

         End Select

      Catch e As System.Exception
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString)
      End Try

   End Sub

   Public Sub OnDisconnection(ByVal RemoveMode As Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode, _
      ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnDisconnection

      Try

         If Not (myStandardCommandBarControl Is Nothing) Then
            myStandardCommandBarControl.Delete()
         End If

         If Not (myCodeWindowCommandBarControl Is Nothing) Then
            myCodeWindowCommandBarControl.Delete()
         End If

         If Not (myToolsCommandBarControl Is Nothing) Then
            myToolsCommandBarControl.Delete()
         End If

         If Not (myTemporaryToolbar Is Nothing) Then
            myTemporaryToolbar.Delete()
         End If

         If Not (myTemporaryCommandBarPopup Is Nothing) Then
            myTemporaryCommandBarPopup.Delete()
         End If

      Catch e As System.Exception
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString)
      End Try

   End Sub

   Public Sub OnBeginShutdown(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnBeginShutdown
   End Sub

   Public Sub OnAddInsUpdate(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnAddInsUpdate
   End Sub

   Public Sub OnStartupComplete(ByRef custom As System.Array) Implements _
      Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2.OnStartupComplete
   End Sub

   Public Sub Exec(ByVal cmdName As String, ByVal executeOption As vsCommandExecOption, _
      ByRef varIn As Object, ByRef varOut As Object, ByRef handled As Boolean) Implements IDTCommandTarget.Exec

      handled = False

      If (executeOption = vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault) Then

         If cmdName = addInInstance.ProgID & "." & MY_COMMAND_NAME Then

            handled = True
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Command executed.")

         End If

      End If

   End Sub

   Public Sub QueryStatus(ByVal cmdName As String, ByVal neededText As vsCommandStatusTextWanted, _
      ByRef statusOption As vsCommandStatus, ByRef commandText As Object) Implements IDTCommandTarget.QueryStatus

      If neededText = EnvDTE.vsCommandStatusTextWanted.vsCommandStatusTextWantedNone Then

         If cmdName = addInInstance.ProgID & "." & MY_COMMAND_NAME Then
            statusOption = CType(vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled + _
               vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported, vsCommandStatus)
         Else
            statusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusUnsupported
         End If

      End If

   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: CommandBar is not a known type in my editor. Maybe there is an "imports" to add? Thanks!

Comment: commandbars and toolbars becomes from the Visual Studio .NET IDE from an add-in. Are you using it?

Comment: If that answers, I use visual studio 2015

Comment: Sure... well, this example applies to older version, (this ones [Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2002 Enterprise Developer, Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2002 Professional Edition, Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 Enterprise Architect, Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 Enterprise Developer, Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 Professional Edition] )